# .Net web service works when I invoked but fails when I browse

Tags: .net, web-services

So I made a web service in .Net. Its for encrypting passwords but I also have a hello world method for testing. When I go to **MyServer/Encryption/Encrypt.asmx** I can see all of my methods there. Then when I select one Im brought to the method page, then when I invoke it works perfectly fine. So for my hello world method Im brought to **MyServer/Encryption/Encrypt.asmx?op=hello**, then I invoke the method and a new tab opens with the address **MyServer/Encryption/Encrypt.asmx/hello**

However, when I try to put **MyServer/Encryption/Encrypt.asmx/hello** into a browser myself I get an error page saying:

```
Server Error in '/Encryption' Application.

Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/hello'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the
current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information
about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is
unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/hello'.
```

I dont understand why that is happening. Is there some setting or something I have to change to be able to just call my methods through the browser?

I thought I could pass in parameters with decrypt?param1=val1, but it seems i was wrong

Comment: > then I invoke the method and a new tab opens with the address MyServer/Encryption/Encrypt.asmx/hello

can you describe the steps that you do on the server side in order to open this tab?

Comment: I didnt do anything to make that happen, it happens by default.